# Interpret columns of zeros and ones as binary and store as an integer column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, binary, integer

I have a dataframe of zeros and ones.  I want to treat each column as if its values were a binary representation of an integer.  What is easiest way to make this conversion?

I want this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1]])

print df

   0  1  2
0  1  0  1
1  1  1  0
2  0  1  1
3  0  0  1
```

converted to:

```
0    12
1     6
2    11
dtype: int64
```

As efficiently as possible.

Comment: Multiply each column with the relevant power of two and add the resulting columns?

Comment: @Evert Yes, that just occurred to me as well.  Convenient with the index I specified.

Comment: I find this makes more sense if you transpose the dataset first: you're now "summing" values in each column, but your end result shows rows with a single number; I had expected columns with a single number. When transposed, it's easy to sum across columns, instead of summing across rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar solution, but more faster:

```
print (df.T.dot(1 << np.arange(df.shape[0] - 1, -1, -1)))
0    12
1     6
2    11
dtype: int64
```

**Timings**:

```
In [81]: %timeit df.apply(lambda col: int(''.join(str(v) for v in col), 2))
The slowest run took 5.66 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 264 µs per loop

In [82]: %timeit (df.T*(1 << np.arange(df.shape[0]-1, -1, -1))).sum(axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 492 µs per loop

In [83]: %timeit (df.T.dot(1 << np.arange(df.shape[0] - 1, -1, -1)))
The slowest run took 6.14 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 204 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a string from the column values and then use `int(binary_string, base=2)` to convert to integer:

```
df.apply(lambda col: int(''.join(str(v) for v in col), 2))
Out[6]: 
0    12
1     6
2    11
dtype: int64
```

Not sure about efficiency, multiplying by the relevant powers of 2 then summing probably takes better advantage of fast numpy operations, this is probably more convenient though.

Answer (score 1):

Similar in concept to [`@jezrael's solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37650516/3293881) that used `dot-product`, but with couple of improvements. We can avoid the transpose by bringing the 2-powered range array from the front for the `dot-product`. This would be beneficial for large arrays, as transposing them would have some overhead. Also, operating on NumPy arrays would be better for these number crunching cases, so we could operate on `df.values` instead. At the end, we need to convert to pandas series/dataframe for the final output.

Thus, combining these two improvements, the modified implementation would be -

```
pd.Series((2**np.arange(df.shape[0]-1,-1,-1)).dot(df.values))
```

Runtime test -

```
In [159]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,(4,10000)))

In [160]: p1 = pd.Series((2**np.arange(df.shape[0]-1,-1,-1)).dot(df.values))

# @jezrael's solution
In [161]: p2 = (df.T.dot(1 << np.arange(df.shape[0] - 1, -1, -1)))

In [162]: np.allclose(p1.values, p2.values)
Out[162]: True

In [163]: %timeit pd.Series((2**np.arange(df.shape[0]-1,-1,-1)).dot(df.values))
1000 loops, best of 3: 268 µs per loop

# @jezrael's solution
In [164]: %timeit (df.T.dot(1 << np.arange(df.shape[0] - 1, -1, -1)))
1000 loops, best of 3: 554 µs per loop
```