# Left shift inconsistancy

Tags: python, numpy

I asked a question yesterday that was beautifully [answered by @jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37650516/2336654)

In this he used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1]])

print (df.T.dot(1 << np.arange(df.shape[0] - 1, -1, -1)))

0    12
1     6
2    11
dtype: int64
```

The `1 << np.arange(df.shape[0])` works great for `df.shape[0]` less than 30 but blows up after that.  This is also understandable considering a data type of int32 or int64.  There will be a limit.  However, when I just perform a left shift `<<` with an `int` operand, it returns a `long` and keeps the accuracy.  How do I get use numpy to get the same result as when I use `1 << 60`?

Here's what I ran:

```
import numpy as np



for n in range(0, 61, 10):
    a = np.arange(n + 1, dtype=int)

    pstr = "for n = {:<5d}; 1 << a[-1] = {:<12d}; 1 << n = {:<12d}" 
    print pstr.format(n, 1 << a[-1], 1 << n)

for n = 0    ; 1 << a[-1] = 1           ; 1 << n = 1           
for n = 10   ; 1 << a[-1] = 1024        ; 1 << n = 1024        
for n = 20   ; 1 << a[-1] = 1048576     ; 1 << n = 1048576     
for n = 30   ; 1 << a[-1] = 1073741824  ; 1 << n = 1073741824  
for n = 40   ; 1 << a[-1] = 256         ; 1 << n = 1099511627776
for n = 50   ; 1 << a[-1] = 262144      ; 1 << n = 1125899906842624
for n = 60   ; 1 << a[-1] = 268435456   ; 1 << n = 1152921504606846976
```

Comment: int32 can't be larger than 2147483647, so what do you expect `1<<60` to be?

Comment: @Daniel when I run `1 << 60` I get `1152921504606846976` as a long.

Comment: but this value is too large for a int32. So what is the int32-value you expect?

Comment: I don't expect an int32.  It's clear to me that numpy is delivering an array of int32 or int64.  I want an array of long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert your array of int32 to an array of python objects:

```
numbers = np.arange(100,dtype=int)
longs = 1 << np.arange(100).astype(object)
```