# Combine bit columns in a dataframe to form integer columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe with multiple bit columns, I want to combine them into multiple integer columns. Can someone guide me how to do that? Here is an example

```
Test A B C D E
t1   0 0 0 1 0
t2   1 0 1 0 1
t3   1 1 1 1 0 
t4   0 0 0 0 1
```

Here, I want to combine 3 columns together, so I will be combining {A, B, C} and {D, E} and here is the expected output:

```
Test X Y
t1   0 2
t2   5 1
t3   7 2
t4   0 1
```

Can someone please guide me how to do this in python?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert to `string`s and then `apply` lambda function:

```
df = df.set_index('Test')
a = df[['A','B','C']].astype(str).apply(lambda x: int(''.join(x),2), 1)
b = df[['D','E']].astype(str).apply(lambda x: int(''.join(x),2), 1)

df = pd.DataFrame({'X':a, 'Y':b}).reset_index()
print (df)
  Test  X  Y
0   t1  0  2
1   t2  5  1
2   t3  7  2
3   t4  0  1
```

Another faster solutions, inpired by [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37649829/2901002):

```
df = df.set_index('Test')

#define columns in dictionary
cols = {'X':['A','B','C'],'Y':['D','E']}

#dictionary of Series
d = {k:df[v].dot((1 << np.arange(len(v) - 1, -1, -1))) for k, v in cols.items()}

#alternative, inspired by divakar answer
#d ={k:pd.Series((2**np.arange(len(v)-1,-1,-1)).dot(df[v].values.T)) for k,v in cols.items()}

df = pd.concat(d, 1).reset_index()
print (df)
  Test  X  Y
0   t1  0  2
1   t2  5  1
2   t3  7  2
3   t4  0  1
```

---

Dynamic solution - create `dict of columns names` by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) by floor divide helper array create by `arange`:

```
df = df.set_index('Test')

cols = pd.Series(df.columns).groupby(np.arange(len(df.columns)) // 3).apply(list).to_dict()
{0: ['A', 'B', 'C'], 1: ['D', 'E']}

d = {k:df[v].dot((1 << np.arange(len(v) - 1, -1, -1))) for k, v in cols.items()}
df = pd.concat(d, 1).reset_index()
print (df)
  Test  0  1
0   t1  0  2
1   t2  5  1
2   t3  7  2
3   t4  0  1
```

Comment: Nice answer, but here you are hard coding the columns `col`. Ideally I want every N columns to be combined. the dimension may vary based on the input

Comment: Sure, give  me some time.

Comment: I add solution for it. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function combining any list of columns in binary like this:

```
def join_columns(df, columns, name):
    series = None
    for column in columns:
        if series is not None:
            series *= 2
            series += df[column]
        else:
            series = df[column].copy()
    series.name = name
    return series
```

Then use it to combine columns in your dataframe:

```
X = join_columns(df, ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'X')
Y = join_columns(df, ['D', 'E'], 'Y')
print(pd.concat([X, Y], axis = 1))
```